# C# CR must be followed by LF

Tags: c#, c, sockets, http, httpresponse

I write a very simple HTTP server by myself, and I use the C# Windows Form to retrieve the content of my HTTP server. My C# program always said protocol violation, CR must be followed by LF. I know this issue can be solved by adding Configuration Files to C# Projects. But I want to know the exactly reason. My http server code is in below.

```
/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
 * */
void *httpconnection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/xml; \r\ncharset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
    char *end = "\r\n";
    char send_message[3000] = {0};

    //Send some messages to the client
    char * buffer = 0;
    long length;
    FILE * f = fopen ("/mnt/internal_sd/device-desc.xml", "r");
    if (f)
    {
      fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
      length = ftell (f);
      fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
      buffer = malloc (length);
      if (buffer)
      {
        fread (buffer, 1, length, f);
      }
      fclose (f);
    }

    strcat(send_message, message);
    strcat(send_message, buffer);
    strcat(send_message, end);


    write(sock , send_message , length + strlen(message));
    sleep(1);
    shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR);
    //Free the socket pointer
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

My C# code is in below.

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    contents = webClient.DownloadString(url);
}
```

The exactly exception message is

> RequestFailed: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF

Comment: Please show how you call it with C# along with **exactly** the error text you get, including the exception type and the message that it contains, along with any inner exceptions if available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be because of the `\r\n` you have inside of your `Content-Type` header.  The `charset` should be part of the `Content-Type` header line.

```
char *message = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: Also if absolutely necessary to use multiline (in this case it isn't), you can move the space to the correct place: `char *message = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/xml;\r\n charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - agree - avoid line folding at all cost. for example, IE doesn't handle it correctly - https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2015AprJun/0215.html